# How to remove specific HTTP Response Header?

Tags: http, header

I want to remove X-Powered-By and Allow methods from response. How to remove or add filter to remove these parameters from response from server?

Comment: Is it not possible from Worklight Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your server or in your load balance or proxy or any such HTTP Server. See for example: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/243439/how-can-we-remove-the-x-powered-by-response-header.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add below lines in project Web.Config File. That should help.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```